# Django template language как после фильтра вызвать атрибут?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как мне после фильтра вызвать атрибут объекта?
Наглядный пример из Python:

```
some_model.objects.all().first().name
```

> some_model.objects.all() - берёт все объекты из таблицы и возвращает список

Как я представлял это в Django template language:

```
{{ some_model_array|first.name }}
```

> Но это не работает

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи обычно делают в контроллере и передают в контекст, но в принципе можно использовать тег [with](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with):

```
{% with top=some_model_array|first %}
    {{ top.title }}
{% endwith %}
```

хотя в случае с **first** можно и короче:

```
{{ some_model_array.0.name }}
```